# How to localize UIPasteControl "Paste" label?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use UIPasteControl button introduced in iOS 16.0.
UIPasteControl displays label automatically as "Paste".
However, I want this text to appear as korean.

Although my device language setting is in korean, the text is not automatically localized,
and also there doesn't seem to be any localization option in UIPasteControlConfiguration as well.
How to display the text in korean?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Built-in controls will automatically show the correct language if your app officially supports a given language and the user has their device setup to use that language.

Comment: @HangarRash thanks! I appreciate your answer. How do I "officially support" a language? Is there any setting I should modify in xcode?

Comment: See [Localization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localization) in the documentation.

Comment: Anyone who can tell me where to start? I did have a look on the documentation but not sure what I have to do to change "paste" label's language

Comment: You need to add localization support for whatever languages you wish to support. That's it. You do not need to do anything specific to change the "paste" label. It will automatically change as I stated in my first comment (once you add one or more localizations to your app).

Comment: @HangarRash Thank you so much for your help :) Only in development phase, I figured out that I have to change development localization setting in info.plist :)